# My button isn't being referenced from the xml file in the java program

Tags: java, android, xml

So I made an xml file to try and access a simple button The activity_first.xml file is:

```
package com.example.name.calling.proj;

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="This is my first project. This is a test."
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bFirst"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="First Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSecond"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Second Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bThird"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Third Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bFourth"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Fourth Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I made the Java program, (just the beginning part) which is;

```
package com.example.name.calling.proj;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

int counter; 
Button one, two, three, four;
TextView display;   

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFirst)
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

It then has several errors saying:

```
activity_first cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

```
bFirst cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

```
tvDisplay cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

So, the Id's I set up in the xml file aren't being referenced in the java program and I have no idea why. I've searched all over the internet, from YouTube, to this very site and don't know what's wrong.

Comment: **"...saying; activity_first cannot be resolved..."** - That's because your layout file is called `main.xml` according to your question. For the call to `setContentView()` use `R.layout.main` instead of `R.layout.activity_first`.

Comment: @Squonk         the xml file is named activity_first.xml. Here is a quick image http://puu.sh/KK6d

Comment: So why do you say in your question..."The main.xml file is"?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing android.R rather than your own R. Just remove the `import android.R;` line and the errors should go away. Also, don't declare a package at the top of your layout xml. You may need to 'clean' your project after making these changes.

Comment: I have just tried this and nothing has changed. It also keeps suggestion to import android.r

Comment: @nEXSoftware : It isn't necessary to import a project's own `R` file. It is done implicitly.

Comment: I am well aware of that @Squonk. That's why I didn't suggest explicitly importing it. The problem arises out of importing android.R. You can't use R to access your own resources in that case, because R refers to the android.R.

Comment: @user1544177 Did you also remove the package declaration from the xml? And clean the project? If you did and your resources are still not able to be referenced then you must have some other problem that is preventing the R from being generated.

Comment: @@nEXSoftware  Yes I have done all of this and the same errors still exist.

Comment: @nEx.Software : Admittedly you didn't suggest importing the package `R` file in as many words but *"You are importing android.R rather than your own R"* might be misinterpreted by some to mean that it is what they should do.

Comment: So now what do I do :\? I have done everything is has been suggested, yet the errors still exist.

Comment: @user1544177 I just copied your xml into a new file and was met with malformed xml due to the spaces in front of each line. When i removed them, it worked (the r was generated). You may want to try that.

Comment: @nEx.Software I've just tried that. The Id's (bFirst & tvDisplay) are still not being referenced, and it keeps suggesting that I rename them (in the "(R.id.bFirst)" sections

Comment: I'm not real sure what else to tell you. It works fine for me after performing the above steps. The only other thing I did was add the xml prolog at the top of the layout before the LinearLayout.

Comment: :| don't know what to do now.

Comment: Here's the xml that works for me: http://pastebin.com/xLrX1Smx and here is the java: http://pastebin.com/D12FhY5Z ... Obviously my package is different and I've a much simpler java, but it's close enough that it should work the same.

Comment: Tried to copy and paste it in and it still told me to import all of these android.widget things (for the java)

Comment: Well, that's because you are referencing specific widgets (TextView, Button). Go ahead and import them. That's just a side effect of my Java code being simplified from yours. The main point of posting the Java was to show that you should not have to import anything to reference R.

Comment: Told me to import the android.R thing :o and the references to the Id's from the XML still aren't successfully referenced, so I just changed the Id's to button1 and button2, because it kept suggesting that on the Java program and wouldn't let me keep the original Id names without there being an error

Comment: I think you'd have to show us more to help further. With what you've given us everything suggested so far should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. delete `package com.example.name.calling.proj;` from your layout file
2. delete  `import android.R;` from your activity
3. name your layout file `activity_first.xml` and not `main.xml`
4. replace `Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFirst)` with `one
   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFirst)` because you declared your button one as an attribute of your Activity Class
5. Clean your Project

Comment: I have done all of this and nothing has changed on the project. The same suggestions/errors are still present.